# Does informix have a "materialized view" equivalent or DB-table syncing

Tags: informix, materialized-views

**Question:** Does Informix have a construct equivalent to Oracle's "materialized view" or is there a better way to synchronize two tables (not DB's) accross a DB link? 
I could write a sync myself (was asked to) but that seems like re-inventing the wheel.

**Background:** Recently we had to split (one part of DB one one server, the other part on the other server) a monolithic Informix 9.30 DB (Valent's MPM) since the combination of AppServer and DB server couldn't handle the load anymore.

In doing this we had to split a user defined table space (KPI Repository) aranged in a star shema of huge fact tables and well defined dimension tables.

Unfortunately a telco manager decided to centralize the dimension tables (Normalization, no data redundancy, no coding needed) on one machine and thus make them available as views over a DB-link on the other machine. This is both slow and unstable, as it every now and then crashes the DB server if the view is used in sub-queries (demonstrable), very uncool on a producton server

Comment: A Informix Global TEMP Table can be util for you,  see this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_busug.doc/c_fgl_odiagora_026.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be getting your requirements but could you not just use enterprise replication to replicate the single table across the DB's?

Comment: I hadn't heard about the Enterprise Replication .. I'll look if I can find more info about it, thanks for the tip and if our DBA has a good day, I might be able to try it out on the test system.. thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

IDS 9.30 is archaic (four main releases off current).  Ideally, it should not still be in service; you should be planning to upgrade to IDS 11.50.

As MrWiggles states, you should be looking at Enterprise Replication (ER); it allows you to control which tables are replicated.  ER allows update-anywhere topologies; that is, if you have 2 systems, you can configure ER so that changes on either system are replicated to the other.

Note that IDS 9.40 and 10.00 both introduced a lot of features to make ER much simpler to manage - more reasons (if the fact that IDS 9.30 is out of support is not sufficient) to upgrade.

(IDS does not have MQT - materialized query tables.)

Comment: We lose support of the Telco App if we use an "uncertified" version of Informix (and anything but Solaris 8!) .. go figure..

Comment: I've heard similar stories - beware of when Sun stops supporting Solaris 8 (http://www.sun.com/software/solaris/releases.jsp).

Comment: Closure: Valent nolonger provide the DB/ETL for our needs .. They've successfully out manouvered themselves .. The current solution is homegrown and runs on multiple MySql/Linux boxes ..